# http 500 error when attempting to make a post request with python requests module

Tags: python-2.7, http, python-requests

I have a python (python 2.7) script that uses the requests module to make a post to a web application I have running on the localhost. The form that needs to be filled out has areas for data and areas for file uploads.

```
import requests
root = "http://localhost/qatrack/"
test_list_url =root+"qa/utc/perform/17/day=next&next=/qatrack/qa/unit/7/"
s = requests.Session()
s.get(login_url)
token = s.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = {
    'username':'user',
    'password':'pass',
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token
}
login_resp = s.post(login_url, data=login_data)
data1=open('C:/deploy/qatrackplus/python/imgs/test1.png','rb')
data2=open('C:/deploy/qatrackplus/python/imgs/test2.png','rb')
test_data = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token,
    "work_started":timestr,
    "work_completed":timestr,
    "status":"1",
    "form-TOTAL_FORMS":"4",
    "form-INITIAL_FORMS":"4",
    "form-MAX_NUM_FORMS":"1000",
    "form-0-value":"5"
}
f={
    "form-1-string_value":data1,
    "form-2-string_value":data2
}
resp = s.post(test_list_url, data=test_data, files=f)
```

The response gives a 500 error code, as well when I put the input to an .html file, it will say that there is an Attribute error in one of the scripts of the web application. I do not get this if I run the script for a form that does not have a file upload that needs to be filled.

Comment: Well then there is probably a bug in your file upload handling. Without that code, we can't tell you why you get a 500.

Comment: Take a look at the logs for your local web service to see what is causing the 500 error.

Comment: The code is quite long, the part that it gets stuck on is:
    def add_histories(self, forms):

            """paste historical values onto unit test infos (ugly)"""
            history, history_dates = self.unit_test_col.history()
            self.history_dates = history_dates
            for form in forms:
            for test, hist in history:
                if test == form.unit_test_info.test:
                    form.history = hist
                    break

Comment: @OhAuth the log just says that there was a POST request to the url and a 500 response was made. Before I was getting an html output that was saying there was no attribute but this has stopped now

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from how you are passing `data1` and `data2` to the form. You are calling `open()` on the image files, but that doesn't give you any data by itself. It gives you a file reader object. To get the data from it, you need to use something like `read()` to actually get the data from the stream so you can pass it on.

Comment: I changed it so that: data1=open('C:/deploy/qatrackplus/python/imgs/test1.png','rb').read() and I still receive the same 500 error

Comment: I guess it's never the easy solution. I'll keep looking as I have time. Could you try printing the first few characters of data1 to your console and see if it's string data as you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what a .png should look like, but upon trying to see the string data it gave a whole series of random characters and made my terminal unresponsive

Comment: Sorry, that's why I said to use just the first few characters (like data1[:5] or something). I just wanted to verify you were actually getting data from the file. Random characters is what you'd expect to see, that's what binary data will look like as a string. My next question is, does that file upload parameter expect a path to the file, or actual binary data?

Comment: From what I can tell it expects either the name of a file (I assume it must be in the same directory) or a path to the file. In the actual code for requests it says: param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'filename': file-like-objects``
            for multipart encoding upload.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be opening the image files at all. It wants a path or a file name not data. `data1='C:/deploy/qatrackplus/python/imgs/test1.png'` might be what it's looking for, as an example.

Comment: I tried that and the 500 error still persists. I even corrected for the backslashes by using: data1='C://deploy//qatrackplus//python//imgs//test1.png'

Comment: You should only need to correct "\" slashes, Python recognizes the 'nix style "/" slashes without using escape characters. I'm at a loss to your issue at this point though.

Comment: I've got the output error now. When it has the string with the pathname to the file, it seems to be uploading. However, when it uploads the file it doesn't save the file to the web application. It should save as: 'media/uploads/390/randomname.png' instead it searches for: 'media/uploads/C:/deploy/qatrackplus/python/imgs/test1.png'

Comment: So the file is uploading, but going to an unexpected location?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this, I've figured out the solution. It was looking for a filename, however based on the uploading mechanism of the web application it was looking for it in a folder C:/deploy/.../media/uploads/tmp/. Upon saving the files to be uploaded there, removing the files=f parameter in the post request and submitting the test_data form as:

```
test_data = {
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token,
  "work_started":timestr,
  "work_completed":timestr,
  "status":"1",
  "form-TOTAL_FORMS":"3",
  "form-INITIAL_FORMS":"3",
  "form-MAX_NUM_FORMS":"1000",
  "form-0-value":"5"
  "form-1-string_value":test1.png #saved in C:/deploy/.../media/uploads/tmp/
  "form-2-string_value":test2.png
}
 resp = s.post(test_list_url, data=test_data)
```

The files uploaded as desired. Thank you for all the help!